# Why is my MySQL event scheduler not running?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I created the following event in PHPMyAdmin and it's not working.

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`user` EVENT `purge_user` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
    STARTS '2018-10-13 19:54:00' 
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
    DO 
       DELETE FROM table WHERE active = 0
```

It's supposed to run a simple delete query every evening. I'm on the east coast, so I set the time zone at -0400. I simulated my query and it's pulling the correct number of records.

After logging in as root, I added `event_scheduler=ON` to /etc/my.conf and restarted the server.

`SHOW PROCESSLIST;` doesn't show me a daemon, but `SELECT @@global.event_scheduler;` returns ON. `SHOW CONNECTION` shows the event exists. The db server is running MySQL 5.6.39.

Comment: According to [the relevant documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html), "When the Event Scheduler is ON, the event scheduler thread is listed in the output of SHOW PROCESSLIST as a daemon process..." If it's not there, I'd assume it's not actually running for some reason. Try checking MySQL's error log for issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, no error log has been generated. My web host can't seem to figure it out either and it will take some time. I'll post back with the solution if I get one--if no one beats me to it.